# Kendo MVC Grid will not hide columns with media query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, responsive-design, kendo-grid, media-queries

My Kendo grid incorrectly displays the responsive column when the page is viewed on a desktop (width > 2000px).  My grid code is below.  It seems like *.Media("(max-width: 450px)");* in the last column doesn't work.  It renders fine on a small screen. Only the last column is displayed.

```
<% Html.Kendo().Grid<WWT.Models.GageList>()
            .Name("StationGrid")
            .Selectable(s => s.Mode(Kendo.Mvc.UI.GridSelectionMode.Single))
            .Filterable(filter =>
            {
                filter.Extra(false);
                filter.Operators(op =>
                {
                    op.ForString(str => str.Clear());
                    op.ForString(str =>
                    {
                        str.Clear().Contains("Contains");
                    });
                });
                filter.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row);
            })
            .Sortable(a => a.Enabled(true))
            .Events(events => events
            .DataBound("onDataBound")
            .Change("AddRowClick")
            )
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("IndexReplaceStation", "Window", new { company = Model.company, gageSN = Model.id, model = Model.model }).Data("GridSearchData"))
            .PageSize(20)
            )
            .Columns(columns =>
            {                    
                columns.Bound(c => c.ModelNumber).Title("Model").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "telerikGridCell" }).MinScreenWidth(450);
                columns.Bound(c => c.SID).Title("SID").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "telerikGridCell" }).MinScreenWidth(450);
                columns.Bound(c => c).ClientTemplate("#=resColTemplate(data)#").Title("").Media("(max-width: 450px)");        
            })
            .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Height(150))
            .Render();
        %>
    </div>

    <script id="responsive-column-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <strong>Model</strong>
        <p class="col-template-val">#=data.ModelNumber#</p>

        <strong>SID</strong>
        <p class="col-template-val">#=data.SID#</p>  

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use min-width at 320 and 850px breakpoints.

```
cols.Bound(x => x.SectionCode)
    .HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:center" })
    .Media("(min-width: 320px)")
    .Width("25%");
```